# Can't delete session properly in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Following the ruby on rails tutorial (https://www.railstutorial.org/book/log_in_log_out). The logout feature isn't working. I generated a 'sessions' controller and defined a method destroy to 'log_out' the 'current_user' which is an instance variable and is changed to nil when the log_out method is called. 'log_out' method in the sessions_helper.rb.

```
module SessionsHelper
def log_in(user)
    session[:user_id] = user.id
end

def remember(user)
  user.remember 
  cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
  cookies.permanent.signed[:user_id] = user.id
end

def current_user
    if (user_id = session[:user_id])
        @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: session[:user_id])
    elsif (user_id = cookies.signed[:user_id])
        user = User.find_by(id: user_id)
        if user && user.authenticated?(cookies:[:remember_token])
            log_in user
            @current_user = user
        end
    end
end

def logged_in?
    !current_user.nil?
end

def log_out
    debugger
    session.delete(:user_id)
    @current_user = nil
 end
end
```

I use a DELETE request to '/logout'.

```
 delete 'logout' => 'sessions#destroy'
```

The relevant part of the layout in the views

```
<% if logged_in? %>
    <ul class="text-center nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Account <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="text-center dropdown-menu">
            <li class="text-center"><%= link_to "Profile", current_user %></li>
            <li class="text-center"><%= link_to "Settings", "#" %></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li class="text-center"><%= link_to "Log Out", logout_path, :method => :delete %></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <% else %>
    <li><a id="signin" href="/login">Sign In</a></li>
<% end %>
```

I believe the log_out method is not working because the view doesn't change, which according to the line `<% if logged_in? %>`, the logged_in method should prevent the part of view to be rendered when the session is deleted. Where 'logged_in?' method is defined in sessions_helper.rb that returns a boolean value true if the user is logged in.

Entire routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

    root 'static_pages#home'
    get 'about' => 'static_pages#about'
    get 'help' => 'static_pages#help'
    get 'signup' => 'users#new'
    get  'login' => 'sessions#new'
    post  'login' => 'sessions#create'
    delete 'logout' => 'sessions#destroy'
    resources :users
end
```

Entire sessions_controller.rb

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

def new
end

def create
    user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
        log_in user
        remember user
        redirect_to user
    else
        flash.now[:danger] = 'Invalid email/password combination'
        render 'new'
    end
end

def destroy
    log_out
end
end
```

Entire sessions_helper.rb

```
module SessionsHelper
def log_in(user)
    session[:user_id] = user.id
end

def remember(user)
  user.remember 
  cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
  cookies.permanent.signed[:user_id] = user.id
end

def current_user
    if (user_id = session[:user_id])
        @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: session[:user_id])
    elsif (user_id = cookies.signed[:user_id])
        user = User.find_by(id: user_id)
        if user && user.authenticated?(cookies:[:remember_token])
            log_in user
            @current_user = user
        end
    end
end

def logged_in?
    !current_user.nil?
end

def log_out
    session.delete(:user_id)
    @current_user = nil
end
end
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The proper way to log a user out in Rails is [by invalidating the session](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#session-fixation-countermeasures).

```
def log_out
  reset_session
  @current_user = nil
end
```

The sessions work in Rails is that the visitor is issued a cookie with a session id (a hash) when they first visit the site. This is linked to a stored session (also a cookie) and rails keeps track of which session ids are valid.

`reset_session` invalidates the session id on the server which is very important if you want to avoid things like session fixation and replay attacks. It also issues a new session id.

Doing `session.delete(:user_id)` only manipulates the session storage cookie held by the client. So if the client for example sends an older cookie they would still be logged in!

> Then why is it not in the tutorial?

M. Hartl's Rails Tutorial book is not officially sanctioned and while its pretty good at explaining the key concepts it contains quite a lot which is very questionable.

Comment: Additionally you might want to check the server log. If the request is being processed as GET then the most like cause is a script error which prevents jquery_ujs from doing its job.

Comment: Although I understood what you said, the code still doesn't work for me. 
I am redirected to /logout and the debugger says 
    `--- !ruby/hash:ActionController::Parameters
    _method: delete
    authenticity_token:     Ukq7ntitwI2yDFZVp40dHs/LKqq6P0/FKVzcY/k51i3aO7DDcSvnn5B7jqn    SZeXreG1dseLt+2Ha1MNz8iqPjA==
    controller: sessions
    action: destroy`
I know it didn't work because the view did not change like it was supposed to. [Here's](http://tweiter.herokuapp.com) the live version of the website with the changes you mentioned.